# Serialize a custom object with JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization, jsonmodel

I try to create a JSON file out of my custom Object with the JSONModel framework for iOS. I get the Error:

```
-[JSONModel.m:1077] EXCEPTION: Invalid type in JSON write (RegisterBuyerDataOption)
-[JSONModel.m:1077] EXCEPTION: Invalid type in JSON write (RegisterBuyerDataOption)
-[JSONModel.m:1077] EXCEPTION: Invalid type in JSON write (RegisterBuyerData)
```

registerBuyerData.h

```
@interface RegisterBuyerData : JSONModel


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString              *buyerDataID;
@property (nonatomic        ) RegisterBuyerDataType  type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString<Optional>              *title;
@property (nonatomic        ) BOOL                   required;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString              *value;
@property (nonatomic)         NSNumber<Optional>              *price;
@property (nonatomic)         NSNumber<Optional>              *availability;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData*>              *fields;  //array of more RegisterBuyerData
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerDataOption*>        *options; //key,value array for dropDown

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray                                  *parentValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData*>              *children; //array of more RegisterBuyerData but only for special selected value of an options field

- (BOOL) isAvailableForUser;

@end
```

registerBuyerData.m

```
@implementation RegisterBuyerData

- (BOOL) isAvailableForUser{

    return (!_availability || [_availability integerValue] > 0 );
}


+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper
{
    return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"id": @"buyerDataID",@"value": @"value"}];
}

@end
```

RegisterBuyerDataOption.h

```
@interface RegisterBuyerDataOption : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *availability;

- (BOOL) isAvailableForUser;

@end
```

Is it not possible to create a JSON String recursively? When I call the toJSONString method I get these Errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData*> *fields;
```

should be

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData> *fields;
```

So get rid of the extra `*` and try again.

Edit:

Oh, I see. It seems like you haven't declared the types you want to cascade as protocols. So do the following

RegisterBuyerDataOption.h

```
@protocol RegisterBuyerDataOption @end;

@interface RegisterBuyerDataOption : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *availability;

- (BOOL) isAvailableForUser;

@end
```

registerBuyerData.h

```
@protocol RegisterBuyerData @end;

@interface RegisterBuyerData : JSONModel


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString              *buyerDataID;
@property (nonatomic        ) RegisterBuyerDataType  type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString<Optional>              *title;
@property (nonatomic        ) BOOL                   required;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString              *value;
@property (nonatomic)         NSNumber<Optional>              *price;
@property (nonatomic)         NSNumber<Optional>              *availability;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData*>              *fields;  //array of more RegisterBuyerData
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerDataOption*>        *options; //key,value array for dropDown

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray                                  *parentValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<RegisterBuyerData*>              *children; //array of more RegisterBuyerData but only for special selected value of an options field

- (BOOL) isAvailableForUser;

@end
```

Comment: I tried this but Xcode don't want to build then:Type argument 'RegisterBuyerData' must be a pointer (requires a '*')

Comment: thx, that was the problem. I added @protocol RegisterBuyerData @end; and changed the array type to NSArray<RegisterBuyerData> without the pointer.